# Loaded event doesn't fire in UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-phone-8.1

I have a UserControl and the `Loaded` event never fires. Why would this be? How can I get it to fire?

The layout is defined as:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyProject.WP81.GenericPopup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyProject.WP81"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400" Margin="0,1,0,-1"
    Loaded="GenericPopup_Loaded">

    <Popup Name="hostPopup">
        <Grid Name="contentGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="statusBarRow" Height="0" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

            <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="#7F000000" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</UserControl>
```

With the logic defined as:

```
namespace MyProject.WP81
{
    public sealed partial class GenericPopup : UserControl
    {
        public static bool IsOpen { get; private set; }
        public static GenericPopup Current { get; private set; }

        private UserControl _content;
        public GenericPopup(UserControl content)
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::Ctor()");
            _content = content;

            this.InitializeComponent();

            Initialise();

            SetContent(content);
        }

        private void Initialise()
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::Initialise()");

            RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
            rd.MinHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            rd.Height = new GridLength(Window.Current.Bounds.Height);
            contentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
            contentGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            contentGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            contentGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            contentGrid.Background.Opacity = 0.7;
            statusBarRow.MinHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            statusBarRow.Height = new GridLength(Window.Current.Bounds.Height);

            Unloaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                Trace.trace("GenericPopup::Unloaded()");
                HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            };

            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::Initialised()");
        }

        private void GenericPopup_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::GenericPopup_Loaded()");
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            _content.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        }

        public void SetContent(UserControl content)
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::SetContent()");
            _content = content;

            _content.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

            itemsControl.Items.Add(_content);
        }


        public async void Show()
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::Show()");
            this.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            this.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

            hostPopup.IsOpen = true;
            IsOpen = hostPopup.IsOpen;
            Current = this;
        }

        public static void HideCurrent()
        {
            if (Current != null)
            {
                Current.Hide();
            }
        }

        internal void Hide()
        {
            //WinterfellToast.Show("msg popup:", "hide");

            hostPopup.IsOpen = false;
            IsOpen = hostPopup.IsOpen;
            Current = null;
        }

        void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Trace.trace("GenericPopup::HardwareButtons_BackPressed()");
            e.Handled = true;

            if (hostPopup.IsOpen)
            {
                hostPopup.IsOpen = false;                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create the UserControl as follows:

```
        var popopContent = new PopupContentUserControl(); 

        // any UserControl can be passed in as the content of the popup.
        // better if it's small though.
        _genericPopup = new GenericPopup(popopContent);
        _genericPopup.Show();
```

I can see the following in the trace:

```
> 13:00:53.777  GenericPopup::Show() 
> 13:00:53.763  GenericPopup::SetContent() 
> 13:00:53.763  GenericPopup::Initialised() 
> 13:00:53.747  GenericPopup::Initialise() 
> 13:00:53.730  GenericPopup::Ctor()
```

so we can see the loaded event doesn't fire.

Comment: You create the UserControl but you don't add it to the controls of your Page

Comment: @Gunther34567, the calling page has a reference to `_genericPopup` and it calls `Show()`. The popup then appears on the screen. Do I need to add it to the page?

Comment: if you want the Loaded event yes, according to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Occurs when the element is laid out, **rendered**, and ready for interaction."

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. And in my tests, if I add GenericPopup as an element of my page instead of a private member I can get the Loaded event to fire. However, what I'm unclear about is that when I execute `hostPopup.IsOpen = true;` the renders on the screen and I can interact with it,  but no Loaded event is fired (if GenericPopop isn't added to the page).

Comment: setting `IsOpen`to true doesn't trigger a render it just makes the control back to visible, if `IsOpen`is set to false the popup is simply invisible

Comment: I think I need to take a step back and look at this differently. I am confused because I definitely see the popup on the screen. So *something* loaded, just not what I expect.

Comment: Did any of you take a look at my answer? :)

Comment: @yasen yeah you said more info in a moment so I'm waiting on it

Comment: @DaveDev Done! But really, point one deals with your actual problem. The other things are just some observations on what I think could be improved.

Comment: @Gunther34567 Care to explain how a control becomes visible without being laid out and rendered? Anyway, you're writing as if you're 100% sure which you can't be, because you're wrong. No offense, just try not to sound so certain about things that you haven't tested yourself, as you might confuse someone into something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things I find strange in this implementation, but lets start with your actual problem.

**1. Your `GenericPopup` user control is never displayed!**

The Popup that you're displaying is *a part of the user control* not the other way around. The Popup displays a Grid, not your `GenericPopup` control. And that's why the `Loaded` event is not raised.

Two solutions come to mind (and I'd definitely go with the first one):
- Make the `Popup` in code and put the whole `GenericPopup` control in it; or
- Subscribe to the `Popup`'s or to the `Grid`'s `Loaded` event.

**2. Do you need `ItemsControl`?**

I'm not sure what you're after, but I'd guess the idea is to have one item in one `GenericPopup`. It would be much more appropriate to use a `ContentControl` or some control that only shows one element.

Also, your method `SetContent` isn't *setting* the content, but *adding* to it, so you may want to change its name or its behavior.

**3. Some other comments**

That's more of a preference, but I'd define all `RowDefinition`s in XAML and then only change what I need in the code.

Also, shouldn't the `Border` be with `Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"`?

I'd define the `IsOpen` property like this:

```
public bool IsOpen {
    get { return this.hostPopup.IsOpen; }
}
```

This way it will always be automatically correct. You wouldn't have to manually update it and there's no chance to forget to do it.
If you really want it to be static, I guess the getter could look like this: `return Current != null`.

**P.S.** Well, that's it for now. Point one is the real issue, the rest is just some stuff I think can be improved a little. Hopefully it will help you get it to work as you like. :)

Comment: thanks for this. I'm looking into implementing your suggested change but I'm juggling about 10 other things right now so I can't completely focus on it yet. I'm wondering about something that I thought you might provide insight into. If I deploy a Debug build of this to the phone it displays the popup. But if I then deploy a Release build the popup doesn't display, unless I uninstall the Debug build and *then* deploy the release build. Have you ever seen anything like that before? Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: @DaveDev It has happened to me as well, but I don't remember how I fixed it. Perhaps just restart the phone and visual studio?